# Using ggraph with undirected graphs

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph, ggraph

I am working with an undirected graph I'd like to visualize as a dendogram with shaded node labels by a nodal attribute. The best option seems to be ggraph, but it requires a directed graph, and cannot turn my graph into one as there is no root. What are the options? Is there a way to do this in igraph with undirected graphs? Do I pick one node to be the root?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.